# scan pages at page range in word.application for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

> Finally, I surrendered to get what I wanted too,

In the source code below, it gets the total number of pages, the total number images, and paper orientations, etc., it scans the whole page of ms word.

> What I want is:

Supposed document1.docx has 5 pages

IF a user would like to start scanning the page from page range of 1,3,5, SO 2,4 are bypass.

How would I do this in code?

```
    ''GET msword documents
    Private Function GetWordFile(ByRef pNumbers As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
                Dim aDoc As Word.Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(PathnFileName, m, m, m, m, m, _
                 m, m, m, m, m, True, m, m, m, m)

                    ''TO GET THE CHARACTERS COUNT OR BLANK PAGE
                    ''Dim BlankPage as integer = aDoc.Content.Characters.Count

                    ''Add a page numbers
                    'aDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.Add(1)

                    ''Delete the page numbers
                    'aDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers(1).Delete()

                     ''GET NUMBER OF PAGES
                    'pNumbers = WordApp.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber)
                    pNumbers = aDoc.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, m)

            ''Code to get number of images...here.
            ''Code to get paper abouts... here.

                    aDoc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges, m, m)
                    FinalReleaseAnyComObject(aDoc)
                End SyncLock
                WordApp.Quit(m, m, m)
                FinalReleaseAnyComObject(WordApp)
            End SyncLock

            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Thanks, I hope someone has experienced this before.

Comment: I am a confused about your question. When you say scan pages 1,3, and 5, do you mean that you want Word to compute statistics only on those pages, or do you mean that you are going to compute the statistics on those pages?